# asp.net mvc controller return json List<T> unknown error

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm simply trying to send back the List collection from the controller to the ajax function as JSON string, and for it to be recieved so i can manipulate the view.

I've done this before with collections but i can't see what the issue is, i get the required json as per the image link at the bottom. However i see no error apart from "json response - undefined" in the other link for the browser console when debugging.

I've already tried:
1. creating a new SalaryCalculator object of data (which posts back okay)
2. also created an anonymous type (which again posts back fine)

Controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSalaryCalculation(List<SalaryCalculator> form)
    {
        foreach (var entry in form)
        {
            entry.Tax = TaxCalculation(entry.Salary);
            entry.MonthlyNet = MonthlyCalculation(entry.Salary, entry.Tax);
            entry.WeeklyNet = WeeklyCalculation(entry.MonthlyNet);
            entry.HourlyRate = HourlyCalculation(entry.WeeklyNet, entry.WeeklyHours);

            if (entry.OverTimeHours > 0)
            {
                entry.OvertimeTotal = OvertimeCalculation(entry.OverTimeHours, entry.HourlyRate);
            }

            entry.OvertimeSalaryTotal = TotalCombinedCalculation(entry.MonthlyNet, entry.OvertimeTotal);
            entry.TaxCode = "tax";

            if (entry.Pension > 0)
            {
                entry.Pension = PensionCalculation(entry.OvertimeSalaryTotal, entry.Pension);
            }

            if (entry.StudentLoan > 0)
            {
                entry.StudentLoan = StudentLoanCalculation(entry.OvertimeSalaryTotal, entry.StudentLoan);
            }
        }

        return Json(form, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form));
    }
```

AJAX call

```
initialise: function () {

    $("#calculateAmount").on("click", function () {

        var formData = [
            {
                Salary: $("#salaryAmount").val(),
                WeeklyHours: $("#hoursWorked").val(),
                StudentLoan: $("#studentValidation").val(),
                Pension: $("#pensionValidation").val(),
                OverTimeHours: $("#overtimeValidation").val()
            }
        ];

        //console.log(formDataArray);

        Ajax.fn.ajaxPost("GetSalaryCalculation",
            function (jsonSuccess) {

                console.log(jsonSuccess);
            },
            function (xhr, status, error) {

                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
            { form: formData }
        );
    });
}
```

Processing AJAX

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/" + sFunction,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: data === null ? null : JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (response, status, jqXhr) {

                if (typeof response.d !== "undefined") {
                    onSuccess(response.d, status, jqXhr, passThroughData);

                } else {
                    onSuccess(response, status, jqXhr, passThroughData);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, status, errorName) {
                // Handle generic errors if they exist, otherwise forward to error handler

                if (jqXhr.status === 401) {
                    // Unauthorised. Force a refresh
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    return;
                }
                else if (status === "timeout") {
                    // Function call timeout

                }
                onError(jqXhr, status, errorName, passThroughData);
            },
            timeout: iTimeoutMillis,
        });
```

Index View

```
<form id="calculateForm">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salaryAmount" placeholder="Salary amount £" aria-label="Salary Amount" aria-describedby="salary Amount" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hoursWorked" placeholder="Weekly hours worked" aria-label="Hours Worked" aria-describedby="Hours Worked" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row collapse" id="studentLoan">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student loan £" aria-label="Student Loan" id="studentValidation" aria-describedby="Student Loan">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row collapse" id="pensionPayment">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pension Payment £" aria-label="Pension Payment" id="pensionValidation" aria-describedby="Pension Payment">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row collapse" id="overtimeAdjustment">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Overtime hours" aria-label="Overtime Amount" id="overtimeValidation" aria-describedby="Overtime Amount">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" href="#studentLoan" id="studentCheck">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="studentLoan">
                                Student loan repayment
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" href="#pensionPayment" id="pensionCheck">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="pensionPayment">
                                Pension payment
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" href="#overtimeAdjustment" id="overtimeCheck">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="overtimeAdjustment">
                                Overtime hours
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="calculateAmount">Calculate</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Browser console display :

[image: browser console display]

Controller action displaying json :

[image: controller action displaying json]

[controller debugging with form data recieved from ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESNVm.jpg)

Comment: if responseJSON is undefined, then where are you getting the required JSON from?

Comment: That is the output that i am getting from the controller which is exactly what i expect however i'm not getting the required successfull response in AJAX call. I keep getting undefined and no other way to tell what the problem is as all the failure xhr, status and error do not provide any information on the object

Comment: have you debug the OverTimeHours to check the result ??

Comment: I think i've figured it out now, it seems to be the data that gets passed through initially. As i've specified decimal type it needs to be in decimal format otherwise it will be undefined for some odd reason.

Comment: For instance if i just enter an integer it gives me the required response but for some reason the returned json string once parsed gives an undefined error if the type isn't correct. Very odd behaviour which i've not come across before as i don't see why the parsed string would not be output at that point when i can clearly get the correct out i desire and the ajax response function would have no knowledge of the data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, it seems it was to do with the way JavaScript handles decimal values (IE it doesn't natively) combined with the way data was being entered from the input forms.

Explicitly converting the user input in Javascript using

parseFloat().toFixed()

Then passing the data to the controller via AJAX call seems to fix the issue but i am going to look into finding a way to calculate the data in another way.